# Remove element from array, without reindexing

Tags: java

I have the following issue:

I have got an "array" Like this:

```
[0] = This
[1] = is
[2] = my array
```

when "array.remove(0)" - the array is changing to

```
[0] = is
[1] = my array
```

but I don't want to lose their positions (index)...
what can I do here? they shall stay like:

```
    [0] = null
    [1] = is
    [2] = my array
```

Comment: There is no `remove` method on an array. Maybe you mean an `ArrayList`? If so, you cannot achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set array element of required position to null, it will do the job:

```
array[pos]=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling remove(0), you can use arrayList.add(0, null). This will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

java arrays start at index zero and have consecutive indices (natural positive numbers).

There are two basic approaches:

1. replace the "hole" values by placeholder items.
   A natural value with java would be null.
   With strings you might also use an empty string.
2. Use a map
   There you can apply any logic you like to the indices.